# MUI useTheme in a server component

Tags: next.js, material-ui, next.js13, app-router, react-server-components

How do I use the my MUI (material ui) theme definition in a server component.
I'm usually using the very useful [useTheme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component) hook. But this forces me to make it a client component, using the ['use client' directive](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client). I would like to be able to do something like:

```
'use client'
function TopRow(){
    const theme = useTheme()
    return (
  <Typography color={theme.palette.colors.green}>
                    2.2%
                </Typography>
)
```

but without making it a client component.

Tech stack:

```
    "@emotion/cache": "latest",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.14",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.14",
    "next": "13.x",
    "react": "18.x",
    "react-dom": "18.x"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MUI components can only be used as Client Components at this time. The source of the problem here specifically is that `useTheme` makes use of React's `useContext` hook, which isn't compatible with Server Components. You can [follow this umbrella issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/34905) to keep up with the latest updates about improving support for Next.js with Material UI.

Comment: That's.... not good

Comment: @RutgerVersteegden which components would be most useful for you w/r/t RSC compatibility? The layout components (Box, Stack, Grid, etc.) will be the first to support the new patterns once MUI launches its zero-runtime CSS-in-JS package. But I'd love to know where you think we should go after that.